# How to get all the queries which we have used in a mysqldb

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl, dml

I have a mysql database with lots of tables and records in it. I want to get the list of queries which were used to create tables , insert records etc in that mysqldb. Is it possible. I have seen it in Oracle sql developer. If we click on the table we can view the queries which we have used, for DDL. How to do that in msyql. I am using mysql command line client.

Comment: The table creation scripts for the _current_ state of a table can always be generated.  Even when there are utilities, regular DB maintenance might remove some of the information you're looking for (ie, because it's using too much disk space).  What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [mysqldump-utility](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) for that

In Linux:

```
mysqldump my_database_name >dumpfile.sql
```